# MatLab: Creating a Vector

Tags: matlab, loops, vector

Can I create a vector v3 = [1,100,2,99,3,98,...,100,1] using just colon notation?

I've only managed to create it using a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. No MATLAB on this machine so apologies if it doesn't work entirely.

```
vforward = [1:100];
vback = [100:-1:1];
vtot = [vforward; vback];
vtot = vtot(:)
```

Comment: I checked this on my MATLAB and it works fine. Can you please explain the last line? I'm not sure I understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. That last line basically takes the matrix vtot and turns it into a vector. In MATLAB, columns are the first dimension, so it outputs a vector that starts with column 1, tacks column 2 onto that, etc.

Comment: Just a note: the last line created a column vector. I did vtot=vtot(:)'; to create a row vector.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version that doesn't require reshaping:

```
v3 = zeros(1,200);
v3(1:2:end) = 1:100;
v3(2:2:end) = 100:-1:1; %# or: fliplr(v3(1:2:end))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I could manage on a Sunday morning:

```
cumsum([1, ((-1).^(mod(0:198,2))).*(99:-1:-99)])
```

It's only merit wrt to the other answers is that it is a one-liner.  Which may not be much of  a merit.